# For loop not adding iterating no in list

Tags: python, arrays

I am a Python beginner. I am trying to solve this algorithm problem.

You are given an array of integers. You should find the sum of the elements with even indexes (0th, 2nd, 4th...) then multiply this summed number and the final element of the array together. Don't forget that the first element has an index of 0. For an empty array, the result will always be 0 (zero).

Note: this all is in a function, and the input is automatically called into it, in a list called array.

```
length = len(array) / 2
if len(array) % 2 == 1 :
    length = length + 1
a= length
q= 0
for x in xrange (length):
    if x % 2 == 0 :
        q = q + a[x] #This may have the problem.

sum  = q

answer = sum * array[len(array)]

return answer
```

It gives this error:
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**'
 checkio, 13
 , 23

13 refers to the commented line.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `a` is an `int`eger, not a `list`, so how can you index into it? *Read the error message.*

Comment: `a = length`, so `a` is an integer, not a list. Thus, you can not access it with `a[x]`. Did you mean `array[x]` instead of `a[x]`?

Comment: The interpreter even tells you which line the problem is on. It takes ~1 second to spot the problem... Also, `a` for a length? Why not `length`? or `size`? or `len`? or `nItems`? Obfuscated code hurts your (and our) butt.

Comment: `sum(array[::2]) * array[-1]` plus a check for an empty list is all we need here.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but haven't got this yet.

Comment: I understand the close votes, but I'm not sure I understand all the downvotes. At least there's enough info here to diagnose the problem, and it's not a giant code dump you could spend hours reading. More than can be said for a good number of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're assigning the integer `length` to the variable `a`. You're then not able to use index notation on that integer, naturally. I think this is just a typo on your part, you probably meant to say `a = array`.

More interestingly, you can solve the whole problem much simpler using Python's [slice notation](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html). For example,

```
def alternate_summiply(array):
    return sum(array[::2]) * array[-1]
```

would be a compact way of solving it. (Slices are noted `array[start:end:step]` and the `-1` index is the last element in the sequence.)

*Edit:* Furthermore, as you're trying to access `array[len(array)]` you will get an `IndexError`. Remember that "the first element has an index of 0", which implies that the final element has an index of `len(array) - 1`.

Comment: Why `[0:-1:3]`? You don't need the `0`, you don't need the `-1` and the `3`should be a `2`.

Comment: You're quite right. _Edited_, and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use array instead of a. a is an int.
And you should use `array[-1]` instead of `array[len(array)]`, which will tell you index out of range.

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 10]

length = len(array) / 2
if len(array) % 2 == 1 :
    length = length + 1
a= length
q= 0
for x in xrange (length):
    if x % 2 == 0 :
        q = q + array[x] #This may have the problem.

sum  = q

answer = sum * array[-1]

print answer
```

Tell me if it meets your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but no it didn't. It gave another error message: Your result: null
Right result: 30
Fail: checkio([0,1,2,3,4,5])

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Matthias and Tarjei for solving my problem. This is the solution, and the simplicity is mind boggling-

```
if len(array) == 0:
    return 0
else:
    return sum(array[::2]) * array[-1]
```